# Convert Native Query to JPQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a native Query which is shown below :-

```
SELECT T1.component_name,T1.model,T1.models_uid,r.revision_uid     from    
(    select cm.component_name,    cm.models_uid,    cm.model,    MAX(r.modified_epoch) 
 As created_at from cmla1.components_models cm    left join cmla1.revisions r on cm.models_uid=r.models_uid
 group by cm.component_name,cm.models_uid    ) T1  
left join cmla1.revisions r    on T1.created_at =r.modified_epoch
```

I want to convert this native query to JPQL and cast the result to another POJO Class ComponentModelData which is shown below:-

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ComponentModelData {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ComponentModelData [componentName=" + componentName + ", componentModelName=" + componentModelName
                + ", latestRevId=" + latestRevId + ", componentModelId=" + componentModelId + "]";
    }
    public ComponentModelData(String componentName, String componentModelName, Integer componentModelId,Integer latestRevId) {
        super();
        this.componentName = componentName;
        this.componentModelName = componentModelName;
        this.latestRevId = latestRevId;
        this.componentModelId = componentModelId;
    }

    private String componentName;
    private String componentModelName;
    private Integer latestRevId;
    private Integer componentModelId;

}
```

I am using the below JPQL query. But it is giving me error

```
 @Query("SELECT new dto.componentmodel.ComponentModelData(cm.name,cm.model,cm.id,r.revisionId)"+
            "   from (   select cm.name," + 
            "   cm.id," + 
            "   cm.model," + 
            "   MAX(r.modifiedEpoch) As created_at" + 
            "   from ComponentModel cm" + 
            "   left join ComponentModel.revisions r"+ 
            "   group by cm.name,cm.id    ) T1" + 
            "   left join ComponentModel.revisions r")
    List<ComponentModelData> findComponentModelRevisionData();

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 116 [SELECT new dto.componentmodel.ComponentModelData(cm.name,cm.model,cm.id,r.revisionId)   from (   select cm.name,   cm.id,  cm.model,   MAX(r.modifiedEpoch) As created_at  from cmla.entity.ComponentModel cm  left join ComponentModel.revisions r    group by cm.name,cm.id    ) T1  left join ComponentModel.revisions r]
```

**ComponentModel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "components_models")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ComponentModel implements Serializable {

    public ComponentModel(String comment, String alias, Integer id, Boolean isDeleted, String model, String name,
            String vendor) {
        super();
        this.comment = comment;
        this.alias = alias;
        this.id = id;
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        this.model = model;
        this.name = name;
        this.vendor = vendor;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -695799009535171917L;
    @Column(name = "comment", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String comment;

    @Column(name = "alias", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String alias;

    @Column(name = "models_uid")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @Column(name = "model", columnDefinition = "text") // ,unique = true, nullable = false
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "component_name", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "vendor", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String vendor;

    @Column(name = "display_name", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String displayName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "componentModel")
    private List<Revisions> revisions = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Does any one know how can i do this. Help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The above query cannot be rewritten easily as JPA query since JPA allows subqueries only in  WHERE and HAVING clauses. My suggestion is to use '@NativeQuery'  and use the query as is.

Comment: @garfield : I have tried native query too but it is giving me exception. Updated the question. Please check.

Comment: You should find some examples on  '@NativeQuery' and '@SqlResultSetMapping' use. The above query is it supposed to be native?  My guess is no since AFAIK 'new' is not an SQL keyword. The text of a native query is SQL that could be executed against the database. My personal reference on JPA is the 'Pro JPA 2' book.

Comment: @garfield : I have tried to use JPQL and updated my question. Can you please check if you can help me now?

Comment: Can you add the definition of ComponentModel? Are you using spring repositories?

Comment: @garfield : I have added the defination of componentModel and yes i am using Spring repository.